# When to use AngularJS filters instead of controller methods?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I am creating logic to format data in a view that is very specific and will likely only be used once, should I create it as a filter or simply create a method in my controller?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on the nature of that logic. If it's related to your data or application logic then put that in the controller.

However, if it is related to presentation and affects how something is rendered then put that in a filter. You want to minimize code in your controller that directly affects HTML/CSS or your UI.